# remove style attribute using attr jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this DOM like

```
<p style="width: 770px;position: relative;left: -2310px;top: 0px;z-index: 999;opacity: 1;">
```

How to remove JUST the position property? I can't add back those other values as it's dynamic generated by a plugin.

Comment: `$('p[style="position: relative;"]').attr('style',function(_,v){ return v.replace('position: relative;',''); });`

Comment: since the initial value of `position` is static  , could try `$('p').css("position",'static')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From JQuery docs

> Setting the value of a style property to an empty string — e.g. 
>   $('#mydiv').css('color', '') — removes that property from an element
>   if it has already been directly applied, whether in the HTML style
>   attribute, through jQuery's .css() method, or through direct DOM
>   manipulation of the style property. It does not, however, remove a
>   style that has been applied with a CSS rule in a stylesheet or 
>    element.

```
$(selector).css("position", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

**this approach can be used**

```
var string = "";
var arr = $('p').attr('style').split(';');
arr.splice(arr.indexOf(''),1)
arr.splice(arr.indexOf("position: relative"),1)
$(arr).each(function(i,v){
string += JSON.stringify(v) + ';'
})
$('p').attr('style',"")
$('p').attr('style',string)
```